# Loop logic, stuck inside a infinite loop

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop

The following loop acts like a lock, it only accepts certain user input values for the program to continue.

I want to exit the while loop when `selection` has the either of the following values: `"X"`,`"x"`,`"Y"`,`"y"` . In the following I have programmed it to do so but when testing the code and entering those values, the loop does not stop instead it becomes a infinite loop. How do I fix this?

`selection` is initialized as `"O"`.

```
while( selection != "X" || selection != "x" || selection != "Y" || selection != "y"){

     cin >> selection;
     
 }
```

Comment: Check the logic carefully.  It's wrong.  It's always `true` if `selection` is any of those values.

Comment: Also, you should tell us what `selection` is declared as, and what is it set to before that loop is invoked.

Comment: @OP -- Using `||` in combination does not mean the same thing as when we use "or" in the English language.  We say "if this, or if it's that, or if it's the other...", but C++ is not English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while( selection != "X" && selection != "x" && selection != "Y" && selection != "y"){

     cin >> selection;
     
 }
```

Since you were using the or(||) in order for that entire statement to evaluate to false all of the individual statements would need to be false. You need to use an and(&&) since then the entire statement would be false if even a single statement would be false. Hope this helped.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me, my brain went blank. I thought that the "||" operator would evaluate false when one of the statements were false.

Comment: @iSythnic no problem at all. If this answered your question can you please mark this answer as a solution. Thanks!

Comment: @iSythnic hmm that is extremely strange. I just tried it something similar in python and it worked... what type is selection?

Answer (score 0):

You can manually break the loop inside the while loop based on conditions, this is easier for beginners.

```cpp
while( true){

     cin >> selection;
     if( selection == "X" || selection == "x" || selection == "Y" || selection == "y")
      {
         break;
      }
 }
```